# How to get onloading progress of input type=file?

Tags: javascript, html

*This question is not about tracking the progress of file while it is being uploaded to the server.*

In my project, I have ~6GB .csv files that I need to read and filter out some rows based on a certain criteria.

With the known events, it is easy to know when the file got loaded into the browser, but since I am handling pretty large CSVs, I would like to show to the user how much % of the file was loaded to the browser.

To load the CSV, I use the following custom directive:

```
angular.module('csv-filter')
.directive('fileReader', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      fileReader:"="
    },
    link: function(scope, element) {
      $(element).on('change', function(changeEvent) {
        var files = changeEvent.target.files;

        console.log('files', files);
        console.log('waiting for onload event..');

        if (files.length) {
          var r = new FileReader();
          r.onload = function(e) {
              var contents = e.target.result;
              var filesize = 0;

              scope.$apply(function () {
                scope.fileReader = {filename: files[0].name, contents: contents};
              });
          };

          r.readAsText(files[0]);
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Here is the link to my app where I am doing all this: https://ahref-csv-filter.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [progress](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/other/responding-to-html5-filereader-events.html#fbid=Lz2is5BC9k1) event. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

With HTML5 you CAN make file uploads with Ajax and jQuery.

The HTML

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="file" type="file" />
    <input type="button" value="Upload" />
</form>
<progress></progress>
```

Now the Ajax submit with the button's click:

```
$(':button').click(function(){
    var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'upload',
        type: 'POST',
        xhr: function() {
            var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if(myXhr.upload){
                myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',progressFunction, false);
            }
            return myXhr;
        },
        beforeSend: beforeSendHandler,
        success: completeHandler,
        error: errorHandler,
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
});
```

Now if you want to handle the progress.

```
function progressFunction(e){
    if(e.lengthComputable){
        $('progress').attr({value:e.loaded,max:e.total});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-file-upload`. It is a very neat directive that enable you to do multi-file upload and track the progress of your uploading event.

[ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload)

> Official [Samples](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload#samples)

**Sample**

```js
//inject angular file upload directives and services.
var app = angular.module('fileUpload', ['ngFileUpload']);

app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'Upload', '$timeout', function ($scope, Upload, $timeout) {
    $scope.uploadFiles = function(files, errFiles) {
        $scope.files = files;
        $scope.errFiles = errFiles;
        angular.forEach(files, function(file) {
            file.upload = Upload.upload({
                url: 'https://angular-file-upload-cors-srv.appspot.com/upload',
                data: {file: file}
            });

            file.upload.then(function (response) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    file.result = response.data;
                });
            }, function (response) {
                if (response.status > 0)
                    $scope.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
            }, function (evt) {
                file.progress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 * 
                                         evt.loaded / evt.total));
            });
        });
    }
}]);
**strong text**
```

```css
.thumb {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    float: none;
    position: relative;
    top: 7px;
}

form .progress {
    line-height: 15px;
}
}

.progress {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    border: 3px groove #CCC;
}

.progress div {
    font-size: smaller;
    background: orange;
    width: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://angular-file-upload.appspot.com/js/ng-file-upload-shim.js"></script>
<script src="https://angular-file-upload.appspot.com/js/ng-file-upload.js"></script>
<body ng-app="fileUpload" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <h4>Upload on file select</h4>
  <button ngf-select="uploadFiles($files, $invalidFiles)" multiple
          accept="image/*" ngf-max-height="1000" ngf-max-size="1MB">
      Select Files</button>
  <br><br>
  Files:
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="f in files" style="font:smaller">{{f.name}} {{f.$errorParam}}
      <span class="progress" ng-show="f.progress >= 0">
        <div style="width:{{f.progress}}%"  
            ng-bind="f.progress + '%'"></div>
      </span>
    </li>
    <li ng-repeat="f in errFiles" style="font:smaller">{{f.name}} {{f.$error}} {{f.$errorParam}}
    </li> 
  </ul>
  {{errorMsg}}
</body>
```

Answer (score -2):

Use ng-file-upload directive.

check link http://ngmodules.org/modules/ng-file-upload