# How to get the progress for loading an html input file?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to get the progress of the html input file as it is being loaded into the browser?

I have an application in which I'm trying to upload a large file (about a gigabyte) to my server.
I have a basic html fine input to get the file onto the browser and then a submit button, which sends the file to the server. I also have a progress bar demonstrating the progress of uploading the file to the server.
The issue I'm running into is that just getting the file from the html input element can take a long time, over a minute for a one gigabyte file. It's a poor user experience to select a file and then see nothing happen for over a minute. Is there a way to get the progress of the html file input?
I have seen this question already here: [How to get onloading progress of input type=file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33260708/how-to-get-onloading-progress-of-input-type-file) but found the answer unsatisfying, and that question is over 7 years old by now.
I don't think this is relevant, but just in case: it's an angular-ionic application.

The basic input file html looks like this:

```
<input type="file" (change)="fileEvent($event)">
```

Comment: It turns out this is a bad question. 
I was uploading an app from my Application directory. Apps are folders, and so Chrome automatically zipped the folder before uploading it, and the process of zipping it was what was actually taking time. Using a file instead of a folder was instantaneous